# Task Scheduler not executing python scripts after IP address change

Tags: windows-10, python, scheduled-tasks

I have some tasks that run python scripts on a windows 10 virtual machine; for some reason, after changing the IP address, those tasks can't be run. They don't even run when I manually try running them from the task scheduler.

Any idea why this is happening? Better yet, how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the these elements :
output out the following command `schtasks /QUERY /TN your_task_name /V /FO list` ,
content of the python script, and content of the "history" tab if there is some content

Comment: Do you see any communications in Wireshark when trying to start a task?

Comment: on the Conditions tab of the task, do you have the box checked to "Start only if the following network connection is available"? if so, is the interface displayed the correct interface? if you run the script outside of task scheduler, do it execute fine or error out?